# How To Remove Dynamically Generated Div Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove a dynamically generated div using `jquery`, remove button will be with every div. So when I click any remove button, it will remove that div from DOM.

```
<div class="form-group" id="drag">    
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name1" placeholder="Name">    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eng1" placeholder="Description Eng">    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ar1" placeholder="Description Ar">    
    </div>           
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a id="remove" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm red"> 
            Remove
            <i class="fa fa-close"></i>                                                                        
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your code...

Comment: code is not attaching it here ..

Comment: can you just give me a simple example with 1 div @ManuS

Comment: put your code in question itself and we will format it..don't worry

Comment: can you plz give me a simple example @Azim

Comment: @vijayP code is showing when i edit the question but not showing here. dont know why

Comment: I made your code visible, use the `<>` code block button next time when selecting all the code.

Comment: See my answer. @adeelpervaiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '#remove', function(){
   $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
});
```

But it's not correct to have more than one elements with the same id. recomment you to change ID to class

Answer (score 2):

If you would generate a `div` with inside the div a `button`, you can add the following function to let that `button` make the parent `div` disappear:

```
function removeParent()
{
    //remove button click, remove the parent div from the dom
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    //in your specific case you want the parent parent div to be removed since the button is encapsulated by 2 divs.
}
```

This function you then need to add to the onclick listener of the button. Either by just setting it in the html `onclick='removeParent()'` or using javascript:

```
//gerenate div + button
mybutton.addEventListener('click', removeParent, false);
```

Comment: <div id="parent><div><a id="remove">Remove</a></div></div> .. what in this case .. i want to remove the div with parent id

Comment: OP is talking about dynamically generated `div`. so please modify your answer. It can't work with dynamic html

Comment: @adeelpervaiz actually I modified, but ok ;) Give me some time I will update my answer.

Comment: @BasvanStein haha yes offcourse you modified :) .. sure i am waiting

Answer (score 1):

Try like below. Use `class` `remove` instead of `id`, because `id` should be unique.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function(){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="drag">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name1" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eng1" placeholder="Description Eng">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ar1" placeholder="Description Ar">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a class="remove" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm red"> 
            Remove
            <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```